# Python Reading Variable Whitespace Text Table Format

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have this weird output from another tool that I cannot change or modify that I need to parse and do analysis on. Any ideas on what pandas or python library i should use? It has this space filling between columns so that each column start is aligned properly which makes it difficult. White space and tabs are not the delimiter.

[image: Example of table Print Out]

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are consistent and every cell has a value, it should actually be pretty easy to parse this manually. You can do some variation of:

```
your_file = 'C:\\whatever.txt'

with open(your_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        total_capacity, existing_load, recallable_load, new_load, excess_load, excess_capacity_needed = line.strip().split()
        # analysis
```

If you have strings with spaces, you can alternatively do:

```
for line in f:
    row = (cell.strip() for cell in line.split('  ') if cell.strip())
    total_capacity, existing_load, recallable_load, new_load, excess_load, excess_capacity_needed = row
    # analysis
```

This splits the line by two spaces each, and uses a list comprehension to strip excess whitespace/tabs/newlines from all values in the list before removing any subsequently empty values. If you have strings that can contain multiple spaces... that would be an issue. You'd need a way to ensure those strings were enclosed in quotes so you could isolate them.

If by "white space and tabs are not the delimiter" you meant that the whitespaces uses some weird blank unicode character, you can just do
`row = (cell.strip() for cell in line.split(unicode_character_here) if cell.strip())`

---

Just make sure that for any of these solutions, you remember to add some checks for those `=====` dividers and add a way to detect the titles of the columns if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! some of the columns have text that have one space between the words like regular sentences. How do I account for that ? E.g. Name column and the names are emily bland or David Shaw. I want the names to remain intact and not get split

Comment: @SriK that's where you would use the middle section that I mentioned, which splits specifically by 2 spaces and then cleans up the resulting list. as long as the names/strings themselves don't have multiple spaces in them (such as from a typo), that should work